# Як правильно пишеться "всесвітньовідомий" чи "всесвітньо відомий"?

Tags: орфографія, разом-дефіс-окремо

Як правильно написати "всесвітньовідомий" або "всесвітньо відомий"?

В. С. Ковтюх в навчальному посібнику "Репетитор (як навчитися правильно писати)" [зазначає](http://p-for.com/book_293_glava_25_%C2%A7_20._Zagaln%D1%96_pravila_napisa.html), що дане слово є винятком й пишеться окремо:

> Складні прикметники, утворені з двох чи більше прикметни­кових основ, якщо названі цими основами поняття не підпо­рядковані одне одному, пишуться через дефіс (між ними можна поставити сполуч­ник ***і***): *складально-клепальний*, *шахово-шашковий*, <…>, *виставково-демонстраційний*, *бюджетно-фінансовий* (але: ***хитромудрий***, ***зловорожий***), а також узвичаєні: *літературно-художній*, *народно-визвольний*, *підзолисто-болотний*, *всесвітньо-історичний* (але: ***всесвітньо відомий***).

Але в орфографічному словнику (наприклад, [«Словниках України on-line» УМІФ НАНУ](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/)) це слово пишеться разом.

То як все ж таки правильно?

Comment: Залежатиме від того, що саме ви намагаєтеся перекласти: "всемирно известный" або "всемирно известен".

Answer (score 3):

(Хм, чим більше дивлюся, тим більше невдоволений цією відповіддю — спробую пізніше переписати, більш спираючись на правопис.)

Моя думка: **можливі обидва варіанти**.

#### Чому я припускаю, що можна писати окремо

Оскільки слово «відомий» за своєю природою може приймати під своє керування інші слова («відомий у дворі», «відомий на все місто» тощо), то варіант «окремо» в принципі не може бути забороненим. Адже якщо ми можемо сказати «відомий на увесь світ», то ми можемо сказати «відомий всесвітньо», а отже і «всесвітньо відомий». У випадку окремого написання це не складний прикметник, а простий прикметник «відомий» (з підлеглим словом «(як?) всесвітньо»).

У «Правописі», здається, немає правила, яке б вимагало «склеювати» прислівник з прикметником, принаймні у випадках, коли це справжній прислівник, що легко можна переставити в інше місце.

#### Чому я припускаю, що можна писати разом

У попередньому пункті ми розглядали можливість існування двох окремих слів (прислівника «всесвітньо» і прикметника «відомий»). Але чи означає це неможливість існування складного прикметника на основі тих же лексем? Здається, ні.

Хоча у [примітці 1 у § 29.1 «Правопису»](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par29p1hprym1) постулюється тенденція до незлиття прислівника, утвореного від відносного прикметника (а саме таким є прислівник «всесвітньо»), з наступним прикметником:

> Прислівники, утворені від більшості відносних прикметників, як правило, зберігають на собі логічний наголос і не зливаються в одне слово з наступним прикметником або дієприкметником: *абсолютно сухий*, *діаметрально протилежний*, *послідовно миролюбний*, *різко окреслений*, *суспільно корисний*, *суспільно необхідний*, *хімічно зв’язаний*.

— але це лише тенденція, оскільки вжито «як правило».

Якби складний прикметний «всесвітньо(-)відомий» існував, як би його мали писати: разом чи через дефіс? Очевидно, що разом.

Найімовірніше, за [§ 29.1.г](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par29p1h) «складні прикметники, в яких першим компонентом виступає прислівник» (хоча можна спробувати також підігнати й під [§ 29.1.б](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par29p1b) «складні прикметники, утворені від сполучення іменника та узгоджуваного з ним прикметника» — «всесвітня відо́мість»). У будь-якому разі, із [§ 29.2](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par29p2) «через дефіс пишуться» не підходить жоден з підпунктів.

Окрім зазначенного в тексті питання орфографічного словника, слово «всесвітньовідомий» є також у таких словниках:

- «Англійсько-українсько-англійський словник наукової мови (фізика та споріднені науки)» О. Кочерги і Є. Мейнаровича (2010):

  > <sub>[world-famous](//e2u.org.ua/s?w=world-famous&dicts=4) всесвітньовідо́мий</sub>
  >   <sub>[world-renowned](//e2u.org.ua/s?w=world-renowned&dicts=4) всесвітньовідо́мий</sub>
  >
  > <sub>[всесвітньовідо́мий](//e2u.org.ua/s?w=world-renowned&dicts=4) **1.** world-renowned **2.** *(уславлений)* world-famous</sub>
- «The Ukrainian-Russian Dictionary» в ABBYY Lingvo Live:

  > <sub>[всесвітньовідо́мий](//www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/uk-ru/%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B9) изве́стный всему́ ми́ру; всемирноизве́стный</sub>

#### Висновок

Отже ніщо не перешкоджає ані існуванню словосполучення з прикметника й прислівника «всесвітньо відомий» / «відомий всесвітньо», ані існуванню складного прикметника «всесвітньовідомий».

Оскільки окремі прислівник і прикметник — це первісний стан (поява у мові прикметника «відомий» і прислівника «всесвітньо» передувала появі складеного прислівника), то, мабуть, деякі лінгвісти намагаються перешкоджати появі складеного прикметника (що ми бачимо у Ковтюха), щоби запобігти множенню сутностей (раз уже можна писати *якось*, то, мовляв, хай воно вже пишеться *лише так*). Але врешті-решт здоровий глузд (немає сенсу забороняти те, що не є нелогічним) і фактичний узус кажуть, що існують обидва варіанти.

До речі в цитатах «Словника української мови» в 20 томах (а також старого в 11 томах) зустрічаються обидва варіанти: «всесвітньо відомий» — [4](//www.google.com/search?q="%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BE"+%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B9+site:services.ulif.org.ua/expl) трапляння ([4](//www.google.com/search?q="%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BE"+%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B9+site:sum.in.ua/s) у старому), «всесвітньовідомий» — [2](//www.google.com/search?q=%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B9+site:services.ulif.org.ua/expl) трапляння ([2](//www.google.com/search?q=%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B9+site:sum.in.ua/s) у старому).

Answer (score 1):

Ліпше "всесвітньовідомий" не писати геть, ні разом, ні окремо. Це типова гончарівська калька з російської.

Словник Єфремова-Кримського подає такий переклад:

> Всемирноизве́стный – на ввесь світ сла́вний, все́світньо-сла́вний, всесві́тньої сла́ви.

Джерело: [Російсько-український академічний словник 1924–33рр. (А. Кримський, С. Єфремов)](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)

Може звучати трохи архаїчно й пишно. Так, словник давній. По-сучасному я б сказав ***"відомий на весь світ"***, ***"знаменитий на весь світ"***, але ж не цей монструозний російський канцеляризм, котрий духом своїм противний природі нашої мови.

Answer (score 1):

На думку [Національної академії наук України](https://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) пишемо разом:

**всесві́тньовідо́мий** – прикметник

| **відмінок** | однина | однина | однина | множина |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | **чол. р.** | **жін. р.** | **сер. р.** |  |
| **називний** | всесві́тньовідо́мий | всесві́тньовідо́ма | всесві́тньовідо́ме | всесві́тньовідо́мі |
| **родовий** | всесві́тньовідо́мого | всесві́тньовідо́мої | всесві́тньовідо́мого | всесві́тньовідо́мих |
| **давальний** | всесві́тньовідо́мому | всесві́тньовідо́мій | всесві́тньовідо́мому | всесві́тньовідо́мим |
| **знахідний** | всесві́тньовідо́мий, всесві́тньовідо́мого | всесві́тньовідо́му | всесві́тньовідо́ме | всесві́тньовідо́мі, всесві́тньовідо́мих |
| **орудний** | всесві́тньовідо́мим | всесві́тньовідо́мою | всесві́тньовідо́мим ​ | всесві́тньовідо́мими |
| **місцевий** | на/у всесві́тньовідо́мому, всесві́тньовідо́мім | на/у всесві́тньовідо́мій | на/у всесві́тньовідо́мому, всесві́тньовідо́мім | на/у всесві́тньовідо́мих |

Comment: Не знаю чому навели цього словника, він вже згаданий в запитї.

Answer (score -1):

**Всесвітньовідомий** і **Відомий на весь світ** замість **(всесвітньо відомий)**

Залежно від будови речення, слово **«відомий»** може приймати форму різних частин мови -  **прикметника** або **прислівника**.

---

### Прикметник

Пишемо **разом**, якщо утворюємо **складний прикметник**

***Всесвітньовідомий** український письменник Т.Г. Шевченко. (**Який?**).*

[Український правопис 2019](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/%202019.pdf):

**§ 40. Р а з о м пишемо** складні прикметники зі сполучними голосними **о, е**; з першою іменниковою основою на приголосний; з першою числівниковою основою на **и, о, а**, що виконують роль сполучного голосного, та на приголосний. Вони охоплюють:

> **2) складні прикметники, утворені з іменника та узгодженого з ним
> прикметника**: *внутрішньоóчний* (внýтрішнє óко), *довгохвильовúй*
> (дóвгі хвилі), *загальнодостýпний* (загáльний дóступ),
> *загальноосвíтній* (загáльна осві́та), *зовнішньополітúчний* (зóвнішня полíтика), *східнослов’я́нський* (схід́ні слов’я́ни).

то ж ***всесвітньовідóмий*** від **всесвітня відомість**

> **4)** ***Примітка 1.*** **Прислівники, утворені з відносних (зрідка — якісних) прикметників, здебільшого зберігають на собі логічний наголос і не зливаються в одне слово з наступним прикметником або дієприкметником:**
> абсолю́тно сухи́й, валéнтно пов’я́ заний, вíльно конвертóваний,
> діаметра́льно протиле́жний, компете́нтнісно орієнто́ваний, наукóво
> обґрунто́ваний, послідо́вно миролю́бний, професíйно орієнто́ваний,
> соціáльно актúвний, соціáльно свідо́мий, соціáльно небезпéчний,
> суспі́льно кори́сний, суспі́льно необхі́дний, хімі́чно стійкúй, чíтко
> окре́слений.

то ж, можемо створити: **всесвітньо визнані** (вакцини), але

---

### Прислівник

Пишемо **окремими словами**, якщо утворюємо **складений прислівник** (утворений з прислівника **«відомий»** і підрядного словосполучення - прийменника **«на»**, займенника **«весь»**, іменника **«світ»**). [Правопис прислівників](https://filologukraine.ucoz.ua/publ/mova/sulm/pravopis_prislivnikiv/3-1-0-89)

***Всесвітньо відомий** український письменник Т.Г. Шевченко.* (**Як? Де?**)* українською так не кажуть і тому відбувається словозміна на **відомий на весь світ**.

---

РОЗРІЗНЕННЯ ПРИСЛІВНИКІВ ТА ОДНОЗВУЧНИХ З НИМИ СПОЛУЧЕНЬ СЛІВ

> **[Зверніть увагу](https://zno.if.ua/?p=2713)!** У тих випадках, коли маємо прийменник з іменником, між ними можна вставити залежне від іменника слово — означення
> (підійшли до самої гори); коли ж **після прийменника стоїть** прикметник,
> числівник чи **займенник**, **а після них — іменник**, слова між прийменником
> та іменником можна вилучити (по парку, у вікно, у кімнатах, **на світі**).

**Приклади вжитку:**

> Ой сину, мій сину,
> Моя ти дитино!
> Чи є ***кращий на всім світі***,
> На всій Україні!
> (Т. Г. Шевченко, "Сова", 1951)

> Бібліотекар Софія Лунейко розповіла юним подолянам про унікальність нашої країни, про духовні й культурні цінності, якими вона [***славетна на весь світ***](https://podil.kyivcity.gov.ua/news/7540.html). Найбільше дітей вразила неповторна техніка петриківського розпису та всесвітня відомість «Щедрика» Миколи
> Леонтовича.

### [Творення і правопис складних слів](https://webpen.com.ua/pages/Morphology_and_spelling/creation_and_spelling_difficult_words.html)

За кількістю основ у них слова поділяються на **прості**, **складні** і **складені**.

1. Слова з однією основою називаються **простими**: *тиша*, *ранішній*, *розхвилюватися*.
   Прості слова можуть мати кілька префіксів і суфіксів і **лише один корінь**: *на-в-з-до-**гін***, *по-від-**пис**-ува-ти*, *по-роз-**кид**-а-н-ий*, *як-най-**глиб**-ш-ий*.
2. Слова з двома чи більше основами називаються **складними**. Складні слова творяться складанням двох або більше основ: a) за допомогою сполучних голосних **о** або **е**: *пароплав, місяцехід, світло-голубий, працездатний*; б) без сполучних голосних: *хліб-сіль, всюдихід, повсякденний,напівпровідник*.

**Складні слова** пишуться **разом** або **через дефіс**.

3. Слова і форми слів, що складаються з двох або більше окремих слів, називаються **складеними**: *буду писати*, *двадцять один*, *раз у раз*, *так що*.

### [image]

### Семантичний аналіз

[Весь](http://www.inmo.org.ua/sum.html?wrd=%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C) (ввесь, увесь) - с., займ. Означає щось як ціле, неподільне, взяте повністю.

**Сві́т** — це соціальне середовище в межах планети Земля
([**Світова організація торгівлі**](https://uk.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%96),  [**світова спільнота**](https://uk.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0)).

**Все́світ** — це весь світ з енергії і матерії, разом з Землею, Сонцем, Чумацьким шляхом, усіма іншими галактиками та міжзоряним простором. Всесвіт нескінчéнний і неосяжний думкою.

**Все** ([усе](https://slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5))

> Перша частина складних слів, що вказує на: 1) всеосяжність, повноту
> певної дії, вираженої другою частиною слова, напр.: *всеохоплюючий, всепоглинаючий, всетворчий*; 2) повноту обсягу, об'єму предмета чи явища,
> означуваного цим словом, напр.: *вселюдний (уселюдний),* *всестановий*; 3) повноту якості, вираженої другою частиною слова,
> напр.: *всесильний (усесильний)*.

Comment: Початкова частина непотрібна, бо нічим не підкрїплена і наразї на вигляд дуже субєктивна. Схоже, ви не знайомі з структурою слів на [_все-_](//sum.in.ua/s/vse). Вчергове списати на комуняків не вдаться, бо наприклад Грінченко їх теж зазначає: [_усевіда_](//services.ulif.org.ua/grinch/Entry/index?wordid=57363&page=1227), _усевладник_, _усезнання_, _усеїда_, _уселюдно_ ітд.

Comment: А друга частина не дуже відрізняється від відповідї Sasha-и. Тобто ви знов відповідаєте таким чином, де хтось так вже зробив, але підключаєте свої необґрунтовані підсумки, цього разу хоча би суперечностей немає.